# Multer with Node.js not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

Okay, here is my form:

```
<form action="/measure" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="thisfile"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Give us that file!"/>
</form>
```

And my server:

```
var express = require("express"),
    multer = require('multer'),
    app = express(),
    upload = multer({ dest: "./uploads/" });

app.post("/measure", upload.single("thisfile"), function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.file);
  //other stuff
});
```

When I submit the form to my server, `req.file` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, wrote you code from scratch assuming a few things but I found the error. In the Multer documentation, it says that Multer will not process a form that is not multipart. So you have to add that to your form (enctype="multipart/form-data"):

```
<form action="/measure" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="thisfile"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Give us that file!"/>
</form>
```

With that it should work. Let me know if this helped you.
PS: Here is the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: Thanks! That was mind-bogglingly simple. Sometimes it's the simple stuff that messes you up.